# Include microsecond timestamps in log4j logging?

Tags: log4j, logback

Is it possible to have microsecond level timestamps in log4j logging?  This is on linux running Java 1.6.

We have a couple servers right next to each other (synced via LAN to the same NTP server), and I'd like to have microseconds in the log lines.

If log4j doesn't offer this, does logback?

Comment: Sub-millisecond precision is very tricky. The JavaSE API does not (and cannot) provide absolute time values below milliseconds, but it provides "elapsed time" deltas at the nanosecond level.

Comment: It is now possible, for more details please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/49429972/1997376

Comment: Possible duplicate of [log4j ConversionPattern timestamp with microseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376488/log4j-conversionpattern-timestamp-with-microseconds)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Log4j does not include  microsecond precision timestamps. Logback does not currently include microsecond precision timestamps but future versions of logback probably will.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from **Java 9** and **log4j 2.11.0**, it is possible to get the timestamp *even with* `nanoseconds`.

For more details, check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49429972/1824361