# log4j ConversionPattern timestamp with microseconds

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I want to add microseconds in the timestamp of each entry of my log files generated with log4j, is it possible ?

I have searched in the official documentation but there are no mention of unit below the milliseconds.

Now i have a conversion pattern like the following :

```
%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH\:mm\:ss,SSS} %-5p [%t] - %m%n
```

in the date conversion pattern(**%d**) i want to add **microseconds** after the milliseconds value(**SSS**), is there a way to do it ?

Comment: why do you need microseconds timestamp in log messages?

Comment: because i have an high intensive worker thread that can generate more than 10 log entries per single millisecond and i want to know microseconds interval between them ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include microsecond timestamps in log4j logging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382763/include-microsecond-timestamps-in-log4j-logging)

Comment: @Cœur The reverse direction for voting to close is probably better, as this question contains a more up-to-date [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49429972/466862).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel close vote retracted, I'll vote on the other question, you're right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to display micro-seconds, you need to add this yourself.  This could be done with a custom Formatter (instead of PatternFormatter)

Comment: I will write my own PatternFormatter as you suggest it is the only solution, Thanks .

Comment: Out of curiosity, where are you getting your micro-second timestamps from? I have found log4j can take several, if not hundreds of, micro-seconds, so if I care about micro-seconds I use my own logger which is sub-micro-second.

Comment: I have a worker that process a queue of messages and depending on the load it can process more than 10 messages per millisecond, and i log every message in trace mode.So in your opinion is better don't rely on log4j ? What do you think about logback ? Is it better ? Thanks again.

Answer (score 12):

Starting from **Java 9** and **log4j 2.11.0**, it is possible to get the timestamp even with nanoseconds.

Here are the special predefined patterns allowing to get a date time or a time with microseconds or nanoseconds:

- Pattern: `%d{ABSOLUTE_MICROS}` Example of output: `14:34:02,123456`
- Pattern: `%d{ABSOLUTE_NANOS}` Example of output: `14:34:02,123456789`
- Pattern: `%d{DEFAULT_MICROS}` Example of output: `2012-11-02 14:34:02,123456`
- Pattern: `%d{DEFAULT_NANOS}` Example of output: `2012-11-02 14:34:02,123456789`

If you need a more specific pattern use the "*nano-of-second*" pattern letter `n`  instead of the "*fraction-of-second*" pattern letter `S` for example `%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,nnnn} to %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,nnnnnnnnn}` will give `02 Nov 2012 14:34:02,1234 to 02 Nov 2012 14:34:02,123456789`.

In your case, as you need milliseconds and microseconds, your pattern could be something like `%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,nnnnnn}`

> Log4j 2.11 adds limited support for timestamps more precise than
>   milliseconds when running on Java 9.

For more details please refer to  https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html

Answer (score 2):

it is based on [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and that does not support sub-millisecond formats, so microseconds can not be reported.