# adding microsecond level to log4j

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376488/log4j-conversionpattern-timestamp-with-microseconds/50286407?noredirect=1#comment87588754_50286407)

How can I add microsecond level logging, how to create custom pattern formatter for this?

I have also tried log4j2, but it ends up giving

```
12:42:05,972803200 [main] DEBUG Log4j2Test - Debug Message Logged !!!
12:42:05,975803200 [main] INFO  Log4j2Test - Info Message Logged !!!
12:42:05,975803200 [main] ERROR Log4j2Test - Error Message Logged !!!
```

as you can see it gives 803200 microseconds and nanoseconds always.

My log4j2.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
<Appenders>
    <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
    <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ABSOLUTE_NANOS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
       <!--  <PatternLayout
            pattern="[%-5level] %d{ABSOLUTE_NANOS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" /> -->
    </Console>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="debug" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="console" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376488/log4j-conversionpattern-timestamp-with-microseconds

Comment: Yes, i have referred to the same link in my first line. There @Peter Lawrey has suggested to create own custom formatter, i want to know how to create one for microseconds logging.

Comment: Peter Lawrey suggested this in 2011, before Java 9 and Log4j 2.11. A custom format is not required to get the desired result. Have you considered writing a slightly longer running test to see if the output is not an artifact of the test?

Comment: yes i have created my own test, gives correct time till miliseconds, after that just 803200.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behaviour. I believe you have found a bug. Can you raise a bug report in the Log4j2 issue tracker?

Comment: yes sure, also can you please advice me what to use for logging till microseconds, since log4j is not working, i should use logback or sl4j? or something else? i have a big project using log4j, i have to change that to microsecond logging.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what log4j you happen to be using. This feature is only supported if you use JDK9 and new(er) version of log4j ( 2.x).

The format you happen to be searching for is this one: 
**%d{HH:mm:ss,nnnnnn}**

Please also notice what official documentation says, because there are lots of "catches and gotchas". I.e.:

> Log4j 2.11 adds limited support for timestamps more precise than milliseconds when running on Java 9. Note that not all DateTimeFormatter formats are supported. Only timestamps in the formats mentioned in the table above may use the "nano-of-second" pattern letter n instead of the "fraction-of-second" pattern letter S.
>   Users may revert back to a millisecond-precision clock when running on Java 9 by setting system property log4j2.Clock to SystemMillisClock

More info on following link:[Log4j 2.x layouts](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html)

Comment: I am using JRE10, and same format mentioned by you, but gives same micro and nano seconds value.

Comment: It looks like an older bug. Quick checking on apache foundation returns me the following issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1248 thus I suggest that you update your maven dependency (if you are using maven) or to manually download and add a newer library. My quick search also couldn't confirm any reference to JDK 10, so you might wish to reconsider "downgrading". Also, please confirm that your project is using JDK 10, because there are numerous examples where people overlook some auto-feature within their IDE that "downgrades" the JDK without them being aware of it.

Comment: While downloading JRE9 it says on oracle website `Java SE 9 has reached end of support. Users of Java SE 9 should switch to Java SE 10.` . and yes i am using JRE10.

Comment: Also bug you are referring is for nanoseconds, i am good even if microseconds work.

Comment: Can you confirm on log4j/log4j 2 version that you happen to be using? Because it says it affected v2.5 and the issue resembles you problem. Also, please notice this part: "The solution is to make NanoClock a field of the Configuration, with an initial dummy nano clock value. PatternParser now only modifies its Configuration's nano clock when it detects a nano time conversion pattern."

Comment: using `log4j-api-2.11.0.jar` and `log4j-core-2.11.0.jar` , also my program looks like `private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(Log4j2Test.class.getName());`

Comment: Do you have an example of making NanoClock a field of the Configuration, with an initial dummy nano clock value.

Comment: I am not sure on your question without seeing the project itself... what type of config file do you use? i.e. json, yaml, xml? I am personally using XML. You have the documentation on this, but to cut it short - <Instant epochSecond="xxxxxxxxx" nanoOfSecond="xxxxxxxx"/> where you set dummy data for epoch, i.e. current time in seconds, as well as dummy/initial value for nanoOfSecond. I.e. you can see example in here: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#XMLLayout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170843/discussion-between-chetna-rustagi-and-sadmird).

Comment: When running on Java 9 (or 10, 11, or any later version), Log4j 2.11 will enable the high-precision clock by default. No configuration is required to enable it. You can control the output format as described in the manual. If the problem still occurs in a longer-running test, consider raising a ticket on the log4j2 issue tracker.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion. I believe the EDIT in this answer is wrong: LOG4J2-1248 refers to the %nano time which does not give you a timestamp but just a very long string of numbers, similar to `System.nanotime()`. This is not related to the question.

Comment: Yes, I agree, my updated post on this subject raises confusion so I removed it.

Comment: Hi since I was not able to implement nanosecond level logging using Log4j2.11 , i have implemented SL4J+Log4j2.9 using JRE 1.8, is there a way to have microsecond level logging now?

Comment: Correct system property name to configure clock is `log4j.Clock`, you can programmatically get the property name as static field at `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.ClockFactory.PROPERTY_NAME`

Comment: You can setup millis only clock as in Java 8 programmatically:
`System.setProperty(ClockFactory.PROPERTY_NAME, SystemMillisClock.class.getCanonicalName());`