# log4j microsecond precision

Tags: java, log4j2

I am using log4j to send messages to ElasticSearch, with a Socket appender and a PatternLayout like this:

```
<PatternLayout pattern="{&quot;time&quot;: &quot;%d{DEFAULT_MICROS}&quot;, &quot;message&quot;: &quot;%msg&quot;}%n"/>
```

using `%d{DEFAULT_MICROS}` to get microsecond precise dates as per the [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html).

But this gives me only millisecond precision like so: `2023-07-27 15:13:11,848000` (the last 3 digits are always 0)

This similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376488/log4j-conversionpattern-timestamp-with-microseconds) suggests that starting Java 9 and log4j 2.11.0, we can get microsecond precision, but I am using Java 11 and the latest log4j (2.20.0), running on Windows Server 2019 and getting only millisecond precision.  What am I missing ?
It seems log4j is still using SimpleDateFormat? Can we get it to use the more modern time framework?

Comment: What does `java.time.Instant.now().toString()` give you?

Comment: @k314159 this: 2023-07-27T14:39:12.220Z

Comment: So it looks like your server is not returning microsecond-resolution times to the Java system clock. On Linux, the same string contains 9 decimal places instead of 3. So it's not log4j's fault, but it just can't get any higher precision from your server.

Comment: How do you deploy your application? Do you deploy the original `log4j-core` jar file or do you put everything in an uber-jar?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz deploying the original jar files (not an uber jar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `log4j-core` artifact is a [Multi-release JAR file](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/specs/jar/jar.html) and the only class provided in both a JDK 8 and JDK 9+ version is a [`PreciseClock`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/time/PreciseClock.html) implementation. The JDK 8 version is based on [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) and has a millisecond precision. The improved JDK 9+ version is based on [`Clock.instant()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html#instant()) and has a much better precision.

You should check if your system supports multi-release jars. The most common way to lose MR support is to shade all jars into one, but the problem can also come from the application server: older application servers (pre-2017) lack multi-release support in their classloaders.

Comment: I'm testing my code in Eclipse (maven project), how can I test the multi-release aspect ?

Comment: Eclipse should not have problems with MR. You should try logging the result of `Clock.instant()` and compare with the timestamp of the log event.

Comment: Clock.instant() returns millisecond precision. It seems to be a limitation of my system.

Answer (score 1):

I am confused by your question it actually looks like you are getting microsecond precision 848000 (6 digits)?

- One to three decimal digits (milliseconds).
- Four to six decimal digits (microseconds).
- Seven to nine decimal digits (nanoseconds).

Log4j appears to be working correctly for you.  If you want more precision you could change to DEFAULT_NANO.

```
Pattern Layout
PatternLayout has additional options for the %d date format specifier:

%d{DEFAULT_MICROS} - e.g. 2012-11-02 14:34:02,123456
%d{DEFAULT_NANOS} - e.g. 2012-11-02 14:34:02,123456789
%d{ABSOLUTE_MICROS} - e.g. 14:34:02,123456
%d{ABSOLUTE_NANOS} - e.g. 14:34:02,123456789
%d{HH:mm:ss,nnnn} to %d{HH:mm:ss,nnnnnnnnn} - e.g. 14:34:02,1234 to 
14:34:02,123456789
%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,nnnn} to %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,nnnnnnnnn} - 
e.g. 02 Nov 2012 14:34:02,1234 to 02 Nov 2012 14:34:02,123456789
```

Comment: It is not working because the last 3 digits are always 0. I added this to my question

Comment: I do not think you will get microsecond precision on Windows OS.  You should get accurate precision with your configuration on Linux based systems.

Comment: Strangely enough, on Windows, Java uses the Windows API call GetSystemTimeAsFileTime and this is documented as returning the number of 100-nanosecond ticks since the epoch. Thus, you'd think it's got a resolution of 1/10th of a microsecond, but it looks as if it only gives you milliseconds. I don't know if it's Java doing the rounding, or if GetSystemTimeAsFileTime returns a value that always has 0000 at the end.